# Sonarqube 7.1 project badge URL without authentication

Tags: sonarqube

We are testing out the new project badge URL's in version 7.1

As described [in the release notes](https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/news.html#2018-04-17-sonarqube-7-1-released)

The thought was to, e.g., include this in README's on github.
However, as our Sonarqube instance requires login, these URL's do not work.

Is there a workaround for this? 
Or a feature planned to allow unauthorized access to badge URL's?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We've created a MMF to allow usage of badges on project that requires authentication : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1178

Unfortunately there's no workaround nor ETA.

Comment: FYI nowadays this seems to be fixed, but only for the cloud version: Julien Lancelot - 25/Feb/20 3:41 PM: "this MMF was only implemented on SonarCloud"

Comment: Any update on the above? I'm unable to access the Jira project to check, but having Private projects on `SonarQube` (not `Cloud`) is causing broken images for the badges...

Comment: Hi, As this post is very old, I recommend you either to start a new question here or use the Sonar community forum: https://community.sonarsource.com/